# Can entries in a category be reordered?

Tags: categories

Can entries in a category be reordered in a similar way that entries in a Structure can be reordered? If not, how can entries in a category be reordered manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a builtin way to manually sort the entries as you can in a structure.

When calling the entries in your templates, you can make use of the 'order' parameter to order the entries returned. From the [documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#order):

> The order the entries should be returned in. Possible values include
>   'title', 'id', 'authorId', 'sectionId', 'slug', 'uri', 'postDate',
>   'expiryDate', 'dateCreated', and 'dateUpdated', as well as any textual
>   custom field handles. If you want the entries to be sorted in
>   descending order, add “desc” after the property name (ex: 'postDate
>   desc'). The default value is 'postDate desc'.

For example:

```
{% entries = craft.entries.section('news').order('postDate').limit(10) %}
```